USB-C -> HDMI adapter not detected anymore
Since updating from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04, my USB-C -> HDMI adapter is not recognized anymore.
I have tried to detect it with lsusb, lspci, usb-devices, dmesg ... whatever I do, plugging the adapter in does not change the output of any of these commands. It's as if nothing was plugged in at all. (Plugging in other USB devices, such as USB sticks, shows up in dmesg, for example.)
I have reproduced this behavior on different computers using Ubuntu 24.04, with different USB-C ports.
Interestingly, on an Android phone, the USB-C -> HDMI adapter is detected, but transmitting video is not possible (when setting USB to "Controlled by this device", I get the error message "Couldn't switch"). Still, the adapter worked a few days ago with a friend's phone (at a time where it already did not work anymore from Ubuntu).
How would you go about diagnosing this problem?

Plug in your adapter, then Within 5 minutes of the event, the terminal command sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes" will show system logs that cover the event.

@waltinator, this unfortunately did not yield any new log entries.

It's not a USB device. It's simply an electrical adapter using DP Alt mode of USB C. As such I would not expect it to be discovered by lsusb or any other tool. What doesn't work? What have you attempted?

@vidarlo, thank you for the explanation! Before the update, plugging in the adapter into the my PC showed an additional screen in the "Displays" application of GNOME, and video was output to the adapter. Now, the additional screen does not show up when plugging in the adapter, and no video is output to the adapter. I also tried plugging in the adapter already before booting the system, as well as switching between Wayland and Xorg.

I now tried Ubuntu 22.04.5 (live ISO), and already during booting, the screen output was mirrored on the screen connected via the USB-C -> HDMI adapter. So I have a working configuration to test against. The kernel on 22.04.5 is 6.8.0-40, so I installed that on Ubuntu 24.04, but using it did not make the video output work there. So I suppose that there is something else that prevents video output on Ubuntu 24.04 ... but what?

I found via https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2192574 that rmmod cros-ec-typec;rmmod intel-pmc-mux;modprobe intel-pmc-mux;modprobe cros-ec-typec enables video output on Ubuntu 24.04!
